# Will pokemon in pokemon go spawn without data access?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'll be going for a hike in the mountains this weekend. I won't get cellular or data, but I will get GPS. Will pokemon still appear nearby or do I need to have data access to see them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They will not unfortunately, you need an active internet connection for both the spawning and the catching of pokemons.

Comment: Well that sucks, that would've been a neat photo. Oh well :)

Comment: @DanielB. it's unlikely there would be a pokemon in the mountains anyway since they are spawned based on cellphone signal density, i.e. more phones around, more pokemon about

Comment: Interesting tidbit. No wonder the campus is covered with them :) I haven't seen any in my residential area, but lots around parks or public areas, are there restricted areas too?

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Which is basically opposite to how Pokemon should be. Of course it's not viable for the app but you'd think Pokemon would be away from people not near them ;)

Answer (score 5):

From my experience as soon as I lost data signal the game would popup saying it couldn't connect anymore and I was unable to continue playing. So unfortunately it looks like a constant data and GPS signal is required.